# VSCode Python - Code with strange color format

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, colors

after reinstall my VSCode I have a problem with the way VSCode handles color highlights.

For example, sometimes when I comment some code, they stay white instead of green. Sometimes function definition stays white too.

Check this example:

[image]

Anyone have any tip to fix this?

I already tryed to reinstal VSCode again but don't fix anything.
I have latest version (1.55.1)

Comment: find the Textmate scopes of the part that goes good and that goes bad and compare

Comment: @MMachado -What extensions did you use in VS Code? Especially the theme extension.

Comment: @JillCheng only have this.

https://ibb.co/8XzT66x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the Python extension you installed. [This one](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) should be sufficient from the start. Remove other related extensions to see if there are any conflicts.

Otherwise, maybe try to specify the color theme. Go to Command Palette (⇧⌘P) with Preferences: Open Settings (JSON), and add the below snippet:

```
"workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+"
```

Save it and see if the color has changed in the file.

If still not working, try to set the color for comment and function call manually.

At the same `settings.json`, add the below snippet. You can change the hex color whatever you like:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "comments": "#608b4e",
    "functions": "#d3d793"
}
```

Save it and the color will be overriden from now on.

More info, please see here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes

Comment: After changed that in settings.json, nothing changed :(

Comment: @MMachado Try to remove the `Python for VSCode` extension and reload the VSCode again.

Comment: That's it.Thanks

Comment: Cheers! Glad you have solved the issue :)